# Configuring virtualhost for secure websocket using ratchet websocket library on an apache webserver

Tags: php, apache, websocket, httpd.conf, ratchet

I have implemented/tried to implement a websocket for communcation between users on an ec2 instance running linux with an apache webserver. I had it working when i first configured it where my ratchet websocket pointed to port 8081  without any TLS. With this configuration i was able to upgrade to a websocket and send/recieve data - through a non secure websocket. This was only possible through the ip address though and not through the actual url.
I am running the websocket at a subdomain.

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/video"
        ServerName video.domain.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ./certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ./certs/server.key

#       ProxyPass /ratchet/ ws://video.domain.com:8081/

        <Directory "/var/www/html/video">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above solution works when i use the ip based websocket connection to connect to the websocket through the JS websocket API.

I have tried both WSS, WS, with and without ports etc for the websocket API but still the beneath written code is the only i can get to work.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://server_ip:8081");
```

I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions regarding adding a proxypass to the VH but it doesn't upgrade the request. Furthermore, i have tried to create it's own virtualhost and that doesn't work either.

I think it's worth to mention i have a cloudflare CDN the requests are proxied through.
Hope to get some fresh eyes. Been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough rep for a comment, so answer it is.

It has been a while since I have dabbled into this stuff, and my first thought was that you indeed need a ProxyPass, but when I looked at my config this is not the case.

I'm going out on a limb and guess that your VH is the issue here, you are explicitly listening on port 443(https) but I believe wss has another port it listens on, so maybe you could try another port. Other than that you could also try to do `new WebSocket('https://video.domain.com')` and enable the proxy in the VH, this way the secure connection is handled by the http layer. But since the browser will then try to upgrade the request to a socket I doubt this will work.

I should mention that in my case I used websockets to open an mqtt connection, since browser don't implement mqtt this is done via wss.

If non of this works I could try to dive deeper into the inner workings of the mqtt lib I use in order to dissect how the connection is set up.

I hope any of this helps :D

---

## edit

since there was not enough space in the comments I'll place it here:

not related to sockets but to apache and proxies: the `ProxyPass` directive has a counterpart `ProxyPassReverse` for that very goal.

```
<virtualhost IPv4:443 [IPv6]:443>
        Servername knowledge.domain.com:443
        ServerAlias knowledge.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com

        DocumentRoot /path/to/documentRoot

        <Directory /path/to/documentRoot>
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ssll.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ssll.cer

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>


        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
        </Location>

        <Directory />
                Options -FollowSymLinks -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        </Directory>

        CustomLog "/path/to/logs/access.log" combined
        ErrorLog "/path/to/logs/error.log"
        LogLevel warn
</virtualhost>
```

this is an example of my proxy conf for a nodejs app

Comment: Hey @chris, the solution was to not only to forward proxy the requests to the websocket but also reverse. Looking into mqtt tho. works nice with java